# keep status in mvcgrid.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcgrid.net

Mvcgrid.net works nicely.

I know how the grid keeps its status in the following example:
http://mvcgrid.net/demo/formatting
after clicking "view" button in a row: he uses back in browser.

I'm trying to do the same thing, using the same controller and another action but i lose grid status when i come back to the results page (eg: editing or deleting a row).

```
.WithValueExpression((p, c) => c.UrlHelper.Action("Edit", "Users", new { area = "Admin", id = p.Id }))
```

In the edit view, after editing a record:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index")
```

**I would avoid solution using modal box.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution. I have to save in session last visited url.
In this way i could go to previous url (also if a post occurs)